# Trouble with Talend Data Integration

Tags: integration, talend

We are trying to migrate data from one DeveloperPro Sandbox to another Developerpro Sandbox. We are in the POC phase trying to migrate data from Opportunities.

Even after removing the System Fields and Formula Fields from the mapping, still running into the following error
"failed to release the resource in tSalesforceOutput_1 :Unable to create/update fields: "

The list of fields includes 46 fields with a combination of System and Formula fields.

Any pointers to fix this error would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: I came across this link, although it didn't add much granularity: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008sQFIAY and also http://www.codeulike.com/2014/02/copying-data-to-salesforce-sandboxes.html, which is much more comprehensive and may be helpful crucially where it says 'ou will then see a 'Schema of OutputAnimal' dialog listing all the fields. Each one has a 'Use' tickbox. We want to untick the read-only/system fields, like so'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AndyHitchings . I started off setting up TalenD based on the article from Codeulike and ended up here. I have triple checked that all the System and Formula Fields are not mapped. Yet am running into the mentioned error.

Comment: Could it be possible that you have read-only field(s) selected? Field level security could be impacting here. If this isn't a cause, then i'm unsure based on the current available documentation what the issue could be.